Does the Cosmog Research Repeat?
Also known as Cosmic Companion, the Cosmog research. My question is if the this research repeats. A friend once told me, "The research repeats about once a year, and then you can catch the Cosmog again." Does this phenomenon actually happen, does it repeat, and if it does repeat, how often (ex. one year, three months, etc.)?

Please note there is a similar post that I posted a while ago: "Cosmoen Evolution" and I'm working towards getting the evolution, and that is why I'm asking about the research. (I have Solgaleo, trying to get Lunala for the dex)

I fear that you are looking for a "word of god" answer that probably does not exist.
I don't play the game but have tried to approach the issue from another side. Instead of checking if the event reruns, I looked for ways to get Cosmog.




Special Research/Timed Research
How to get
Availability




A Cosmic Companion
Complete 1st part
September to December 2022


Starry Skies
Complete 4th part
June 21 to June 26 2023 (can also be bought for 5$??)




We can notice four things:

instead of running the original event again the game made Cosmog available in a different event.
the second event was pretty short compared to the original one. This seems a pretty good  FOMO strategy: "I have lost the original run, now I only got 5 day, I should buy the second ticket just in case I can't complete the event in time"
the second event only gave players a second chance to get Cosmog but did not provide any candy. So based on my understanding you are stuck either using the wildcard "rare candies" (that I bet can be bought with real money in some in game cash shop) or... slowly grind your way to 100 candies for the evolution one candy at time by walking with said pokemon as your buddy
the second even could be "bought" at the price of 5$. That way, even if you missed the previous one you could still get the same event  running TWICE at the same time, and thus get TWO Cosmog. Cosmog has two evolution path so... you can't call this "marketing strategy" a coincidence.

Based on this, I would not expect a re-run of the original event. If you are lucky based on the existing pattern some later event this year may provide a second chance. Expect also to be able to buy event to get multiple Cosmog, or even the candies if they "listened to player feedback and wanted to provide an easy (paid) way to get more candies to evolve Cosmog"

Having played Pokemon Go since launch, I can say your summary is spot on. Eventually, a way to get a shiny Cosmog will happen eventually; but that probably won't happen for another ~3 years

@Wondercricket know one gacha, know every gacha.

Yap, no Pokemon is lost forever, they tend to make them available again in a not specified future

@pinckerman [armored mewtwo] "Am I a joke to you?"

@Wondercricket I played for something like 14 months and I own an armored Mewtwo, guess I'm lucky

A Cosmic Companion is a special research quest was gradually released during the Season of Light in Pokémon Go. Read more about Season of Light here https://www.eurogamer.net/pokemon-go-season-of-light-hemisphere-seasonal-spawns-end-date-9004

That wasn't my question. I asked if the research REPEATS

No, Cosmog do not have a fixed repeating schedule. It may return in future events, but there is no official confirmation that it will happen on a yearly basis or any other regular interval.

Correct me if I'm wrong but "A Special Research quest" probably indicates it's a one time thing.

Yeah you are correct, this quest featured in 2022 only and there have been no additional events happened so far now.
